# Phpunit stalls when test is ran in bulk but works if ran alone

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a test which sends an email to a live but dev't SMTP server.

The test runs fine when ran alone e.g., `vendor/bin/phpunit --filter fooTest`. This particular test takes about 2-3 seconds to complete as it connects to an external SMTP service.

But, if I run it together with all tests e.g., `vendor/bin/phpunit --debug`, it "freezes" at `fooTest` without any error message.

Note:

- I have `<ini name="display_errors" value="true"/>` in `phpunit.xml`
- I tried putting `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses` in the class and also `@runInSeparateProcess` in the method, but still does not work

I can probably just mock this but I want to know why it runs fine if it's `--filtered` alone but not in bulk. Any ideas why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How do you know it fails? What is the error message?

Comment: @DirkScholten it's not strictly "failing" just freezes like it's stuck

Comment: Is there nothing in the logs that you can see what is happening when it gets stuck? Is it during the sending out of the email? Maybe it is still busy processing a request from a previous test?